# Matlab: system of two equations with two unknowns

Tags: matlab

I have this task: a function "fun", which is subject to "s" (that "s" has to be squared, multiplied by "R" and added to "fun", in order to get "P"). "P" should be differentiated by "x" and "y", both of those equations equaled to zero and then I should get two equations of two unknowns, which have to be solved. I get an error in "s", saying "Undefined function or variable 'x'." I have a very little experience in Matlab, so I don't really know what is the correct way of writing that line (or those lines). If someone can help, it will be great, thanks.

```
function [x1,y1] = penalty(fun)

s=x-2*y+1;

prompt='Enter R: ';
R=input(prompt);

P=fun+R*s^2;

dPx=diff(P,x);
dPy=diff(P,y);

[x1,y1]=solve(dPx==0,dPy==0,x,y);

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your function is not correct. I have modified that part. Still there is a problem, because I have no clue what do you mean by fun in your code. Otherwise the modified code would probably run without problem.

```
function [x1, y1] = penalty(x, y)

s=x-2*y+1;

prompt='Enter R: ';
R=input(prompt);

P= fun +R*s^2; % What is fun?

dPx=diff(P,x);
dPy=diff(P,y);

[x1, y1]=solve(dPx==0,dPy==0,x,y);

end
```

Comment: "fun" is the external function (I don't know if it is called like that - I mean the function which is defined in a separate script and called in the command line). Thank you!

    function f = funpenalty(x,y)

    f=(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2+5;

    end

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't know the function would be written like that in the comment :/

Comment: So do you want to have a recursive function or what was in your mind?
What should be the input parameter of your function? X and Y as I have stated or something else?

Comment: This should be a part of some optimization problem. Function "fun" has to be minimized, subject to "s", so the algorithm says that it's done the way I wrote the equation for "P" and so on. The initial values are unknown. I did it on paper and got the result, but can't write it in Matlab.